# Why is there a discrepancy between etherhub.io and gastracker.io?

Tags: ethereum-classic

I traded for Ether Classic (ETC) using ShapeShift and my Coinomi Wallet.  The amount I received shows in both my Coinomi Wallet and on gastracker.io, but etherhub.io, etherscan.io, and ethplorer.io all show zero balance.  Can someone explain that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ETC won't show up on those last 3 webpages as they are only tracking ETH. But if your Coinomi Wallet is showing a balance then you should in fact have the ETC in your wallet but you always verify using another source such as http://etherhub.io/home using search box at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think etherscan.io or ethplorer.io support Ethereum Classic, so that should explain why neither of those shows the balance.

etherhub.io appears to be broken. The most recent block it displays is from about a month ago. If your transaction was more recent than that, it's probably not going to show up there.

So gastracker.io is probably the only useful source of those you listed.